# How can I connect these 2 queries with each other?

Tags: sql

I have this query

```
SELECT m.id
, m.userId1
, m.userId2
, m.message
, m.sentDate
, m.readDate
, u1.id id1
, u1.ad ad1
, u1.avatar avatar1
, u2.id id2
, u2.ad ad2
, u2.avatar avatar2 
FROM messages m 
inner join users u1 
       on m.userId1 = u1.id
inner join users u2 
    on m.userId2 = u2.id 
where (userId1 = 7 or userId2 = 7) 
    and (userId2 = 8 or userId1 = 8) 
order by sentDate
```

Result:

[image]

and I want to add this query to response

```
select count(id) from messages where userId1 = 7
```

Result:

[image]

How can I connect these 2 queries with each other?

Comment: What do you mean by 'combine'? Are you asking how you can make use of another `JOIN`? Or are you asking how you can select the count in addition to the other fields?

Comment: @ObsidianAge yes i want to add count to next of other fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest putting the value in the `from` clause:

```
select . . .,
       u7.cnt
from messages m join
     users u1 
     on m.userId1 = u1.id join
     users u2 
     on m.userId2 = u2.id cross join
     (select count(*)  as cnt from messages where userId1 = 7) u7
where 7 in (m.userId1, m.userId2) and
      8 in (m.userId2, m.userId1) 
order by sentDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested (I'm not at a sql-connected box right now) but one way might be something like this:

```
(SELECT m.id
, m.userId1
, m.userId2
, m.message
, m.sentDate
, m.readDate
, (SELECT Count() from messages mm where mm.userId1 = 7) as countUserId1
, u1.id id1
, u1.ad ad1
, u1.avatar avatar1
, u2.id id2
, u2.ad ad2
, u2.avatar avatar2 
FROM 
    (messages m 
    inner join users u1 
    on m.userId1 = u1.id) 
inner join users u2 
on m.userId2 = u2.id 
where (userId1 = 7 or userId2 = 7) 
and (userId2 = 8 or userId1 = 8) 
order by sentDate)
```

Depending on what you are doing, there are likely better approaches for performance...